How to avoid NATS stale connection error on node.js?
I'm working on a web application and I leave it without interaction for some time. At the backend there's NATS server. I'm facing a stale connection error with NATS on node.js. I need some help and guidance to fix this. How to avoid this from occurring?
NATS server NatsError: STALE CONNECTION
    at ProtocolHandler.toError (/app/node_modules/ts-nats/lib/protocolhandler.js:895:20)

    at ProtocolHandler.processErr (/app/node_modules/ts-nats/lib/protocolhandler.js:906:35)

    at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/ts-nats/lib/protocolhandler.js:1006:26)

    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:571:11)

    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {

  code: 'NATS_PROTOCOL_ERR',

  chainedError: undefined
}


also facing the same issue, seems like related to the PING-PONG command sent by the server, in my case my script needs to 'sleep' for 2s, perhaps when the server pings my script, it's within exactly that 2s window, not sure, just a theory.

I managed to find the issue, in my case I had a uncaught exception that was closing the connection and then the PING-PONG by the server was unreachable, after I handled it properly, it's not closing the connection anymore and the 'stale connections' are gone.

I got rid of the NATS and replaced with FastAPI. It does the job and much better with additional features.
